Control direction of container resizing / Whitespace direction
I'm having trouble with the direction a container resizes.
Essentially, I have an absolutely positioned element. I've justified the content inside to flex-end, as I'd like it to be positioned the at the end of the container. As the window shrinks, I'd like for the whitespace/extra space above the container to shrink and the content be pulled up towards the top. Right now, it goes further towards the bottom. I want the exact opposite of what is currently happening.
I've provided a video to help explain. I provide the real Netflix behaviour, you can see it resizes towards the top, whereas mine resizes towards the bottom.
Here is the component:
const HomePageHero = () => {
  return (
    <div className="debug-red absolute bottom-[35%] top-0 left-0 mx-[58px] flex flex-col justify-end items-center w-[36%] z-50">
      <div className=" block debug ">
        <div id="text" className="flex flex-col gap-[20px]">
          <img src={heroTitle} className="" />
          <p className="text-white font-normal text-[1.2vw]">
            Years after retiring from their formidable ninja lives, a
            dysfunctional family must return to shadowy missions to counteract a
            string of looming threats.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons" className="flex gap-4">
          <Button title="Play" icon={PlayIconLarge} bgWhite={true} />
          <Button title="More Info" icon={InfoIconMedium} bgWhite={false} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Video:
https://imgur.com/a/1VoPidM

You are getting the opposite behaviour, because you are using the bottom-[35%].
I am hoping you want to achieve something like the hero page in Netflix ( according to the video you have attatched ).
I have a solution for you. I have replaced the images with some randome movie posters. And I have also added a hero image. You can replace or style it according to your needs.
const HomePageHero = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="relative lg:max-h-[100vh] flex items-center overflow-hidden">
        <img
          className="w-[100%]"
          src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71US0Ha5O2L._AC_UF1000,1000_QL80_.jpg"
        />

        <div className="absolute  flex flex-col justify-end mx-[58px] items-center w-[36%] z-50">
          <div id="text" className="flex flex-col gap-[20px]">
            <img src={"https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/b2cf68a6a2ddb55449a856098ad32b2204ae3cde/0_0_4904_3688/master/4904.jpg?width=700&quality=85&auto=format&fit=max&s=5c172b59350a2f89360c82d8dbfd156c"} className="" />
            <p className="text-white font-normal text-[1.2vw]">
              Years after retiring from their formidable ninja lives, a
              dysfunctional family must return to shadowy missions to counteract
              a string of looming threats.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="buttons" className="flex gap-4">
            <Button title="Play" icon={""} bgWhite={true} />
            <Button title="More Info" icon={""} bgWhite={false} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Check the tailwind classes, and you can figure out that I have a relative div which has dimensions same as the image added to it.
And in the absolute div, the positioning happens based on the relative parent's dimensions. And Now, that I have the items-center in the parent div. It also reflects that in the absolute div as well.
I hope this should give a good starting point to make the UI.

Hey thanks for this. I tried it and it worked. Can you explain it a little more? I want to cement my understanding. Is it dependent on the background image? What if I wanted to not use the background image? Also, when I comment out the img tag with "w-[100%]", everything disappears. Kind of confused by that but it's almost 4AM so maybe I should take a look at it with a clean mind tomorrow. I threw it on a replit if you want to take a look / make any changes easily: https://replit.com/join/jbizfabivt-paradimes

The image is for giving the container a dimension ( width & height ). If you don't want an image, you will have to give the parent container ( which has the position relative ) width and height by yourself. And then the text container which you have made absolute, will layout itself according to the parent relative container.

I will check the replit. I will try to add some comments there.

Try to anchor your container at the bottom using bottom-0 and ditch the top-0 and bottom-[35%]. This lets your content shift up as the screen gets smaller.
const HomePageHero = () => {
  return (
    <div className="debug-red absolute bottom-0 left-0 mx-[58px] flex flex-col justify-end items-center w-[36%] z-50">
      <div className=" block debug ">
        <div id="text" className="flex flex-col gap-[20px]">
          <img src={heroTitle} className="" />
          <p className="text-white font-normal text-[1.2vw]">
            Years after retiring from their formidable ninja lives, a
            dysfunctional family must return to shadowy missions to counteract a
            string of looming threats.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons" className="flex gap-4">
          <Button title="Play" icon={PlayIconLarge} bgWhite={true} />
          <Button title="More Info" icon={InfoIconMedium} bgWhite={false} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


I tried this but now it goes to the absolute bottom of the screen as you shrink the window. I' m not sure if this is the right use case for it and I don't entirely know how to use, but I created a replit, if you want to check it out, maybe you could make some changes somehow and I could see, so we're on the same page. https://replit.com/join/jbizfabivt-paradimes

Change justify-end to justify-start in the container to align items to the top.
Change bottom-[35%] to top-[35%] to position the element relative to the top instead of the bottom.


const HomePageHero = () => {
  return (
    <div className="debug-red absolute top-[35%] bottom-0 left-0 mx-[58px] flex flex-col justify-start items-center w-[36%] z-50">
      <div className="block debug">
        <div id="text" className="flex flex-col gap-[20px]">
          <img src={heroTitle} className="" />
          <p className="text-white font-normal text-[1.2vw]">
            Years after retiring from their formidable ninja lives, a
            dysfunctional family must return to shadowy missions to counteract a
            string of looming threats.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons" className="flex gap-4">
          <Button title="Play" icon={PlayIconLarge} bgWhite={true} />
          <Button title="More Info" icon={InfoIconMedium} bgWhite={false} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};




I tried this but now it just gravitates towards the center of the screen as you resize the window. I made a replit for it incase you want to make any changes: https://replit.com/join/jbizfabivt-paradimes
